# Is there any way to get Akka Streams' groupedWithin to emit empty groups?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

In the following code, `tick` emits a new object every three seconds. I'm trying to count the number of emitted objects every second using `groupedWithin` (which ignores empty groups). Is there any way in Akka Streams for the following code to print `0` in periods when `tick` does not emit any objects?

```
Source.tick(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofSeconds(3), new Object())
    .groupedWithin(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .map(List::size)
    .runWith(Sink.foreach(e -> System.out.println(e)), materializer);
```

In other words, I'd like the output of this code to be this sequence: `1 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...` (every second) instead of `1 1 1 ...` (every three seconds).

**EDIT**: This is the best workaround I have come up with so far (using `keepAlive` to send some special objects if the upstream is idle):

```
Source.tick(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofSeconds(3), new Object())
    .keepAlive(Duration.ofSeconds(1), KeepAliveElement::new)
    .groupedWithin(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .map(lst -> lst.stream().filter(e -> !(e instanceof KeepAliveElement)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .map(List::size)
    .runWith(Sink.foreach(e -> System.out.println(e)), materializer);
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this would be of normal difficulty, I was wrong. One thing I wanted to do is to ensure that the flow counting items that pass through the stream does not keep a reference to each item it sees: if many items pass in the aggregation period, you will end up with an unnecessarily big list in memory (even if only for a second) and the performance penalty to add (many) items to it. The following solution, although complex, keeps only a counter.

**NOTE:** Although I tested the happy scenario, I cannot say this is battle-proven, so use with caution!

Based on Akka's `GroupedWeightedWithin` and the documentation [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-cookbook.html#create-a-stream-processor-that-repeats-the-last-element-seen):

```java
public class CountInPeriod<T> extends GraphStage<FlowShape<T, Integer>> {
    public Inlet<T> in = Inlet.<T>create("CountInPeriod.in");
    public Outlet<Integer> out = Outlet.<Integer>create("CountInPeriod.out");
    private FlowShape<T, Integer> shape = FlowShape.of(in, out);
    private Duration duration;

    public CountInPeriod(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public GraphStageLogic createLogic(Attributes inheritedAttributes) {
        return new TimerGraphStageLogic(shape) {
            private int counter = 0;
            private int bufferPushCounter = -1;

            {
                setHandler(in, new AbstractInHandler() {
                    @Override public void onPush() throws Exception, Exception {
                        grab(in);
                        counter++;
                        pull(in);
                    }
                });
                setHandler(out, new AbstractOutHandler() {
                    @Override public void onPull() throws Exception, Exception {
                        if (bufferPushCounter >= 0) {
                            push(out, bufferPushCounter);
                            bufferPushCounter = -1;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void preStart() throws Exception, Exception {
                scheduleWithFixedDelay(CountInPeriod.class, duration, duration);
                pull(in);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTimer(Object timerKey) throws Exception, Exception {
                if (isAvailable(out)) emitCounter();
                else bufferPush();
            }

            private void emitCounter() {
                push(out, counter);
                counter = 0;
                bufferPushCounter = -1;
            }

            private void bufferPush() {
                bufferPushCounter = counter;
                counter = 0;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public FlowShape<T, Integer> shape() {
        return shape;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```java
public class GroupTicked {
    final static ActorSystem as = ActorSystem.create("as");

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        CompletionStage<Done> done = Source.tick(Duration.ZERO, Duration.ofSeconds(3), new Object())
                .take(7) // to finish in finite time...
                .via(new CountInPeriod<>(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
                .runWith(Sink.foreach(e -> System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " -> " + e)), as);
        done.thenAccept(x -> as.terminate());
    }
}
```